# Why new installed apache2 not starting in Ubuntu Server 20

Tags: apache2

Installed new Ubuntu Server 20. Then tried to install apache2 but got these errors and apache not starting.

```
Aug 16 21:06:47 xxx apachectl[2563820]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message 
Aug 16 21:06:47 xxx apachectl[2563820]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
Aug 16 21:06:47 xxx apachectl[2563820]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Aug 16 21:06:47 xxx apachectl[2563820]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Aug 16 21:06:47 xxx apachectl[2563820]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Aug 16 21:06:47 xxx apachectl[2563802]: Action 'start' failed.
Aug 16 21:06:47 xxx apachectl[2563802]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Aug 16 21:06:47 xxx systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 16 21:06:47 xxx systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 16 21:06:47 xxx systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.2) ...
```

Comment: The Apache error log may have more information.

Answer (score 2):

please post the output of

```
netstat -tulpen | grep 80
```

it seems port 80 is already in use.

See your error log:

```
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

Comment: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          83755      -              
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2380          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          60497      -              
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          72751      -              
udp6       0      0 fe80::a6ba:dbff:fe4:546 :::*                                100        18334      -

Comment: hmm, it seems no other process is running on port 80. can you please post the apache2 log? use "cat /var/log/syslog | grep apache2" and please show ports.conf with "cat /etc/apache2/ports.conf". For the error "AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message": you can edit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and insert "ServerName localhost"

Comment: oh wait, it runs a process on port 80:  tcp6 0 0 :::80 :::* LISTEN 0 72751  use "sudo netstat -tulpen | grep 80" to show wich process is using port 80. So you have to edit the port for this process to another port oder change /etc/apache2/ports.conf port 80 to another port except 80 or 8080, this port is also already in use on your system.